Script for InDesign That Can Export Each Spread of a Document As 2-Page PDF's, AND Name The PDF's Based on Specific Table Cell
Before I explain what I need to happen, I think it'd be helpful to explain the document I'll be working on:
With InDesign, using the data merge functionality, I will create a document where each spread will be the front and back page of a product spec sheet (letter size, 2-sided).
What I'm hoping a script can do, is to export every spread as it's own PDF, and name the PDFs based on the model number of the product shown on each spread.
So for example, let's say the data merge was 25 records. That'd be 25 spreads (50 pages), starting on page 2. The export would create a PDF of pages 2-3, a PDF of 4-5, of 6-7, and so on. The export process would also extract the model number which would be consistently located in a table on left page, and use the model number to name the PDF it's creating.
It seemed more doable when it was just in my head. Now that I've typed it out I'm not as optimistic. But I'm also a scripting simpleton so hopefully any skilled folks can chime in on the viability of the idea.
Thanks!
*edit to say that I used 25 records just as an example. The project will be for hundreds of spec sheets hence the interest to data merge and automate what I can.
So far I've just worked on verifying I could use InDesign's data merge to create spreads and not just single pages.
I did look at a script I got help on here that while was a very different process, it did include a step that found cell contents based on the text in the title cell. That's what made me think it'd be possible to extract the model number and use it to name each file.
Screenshot of spread showing the data merge tags

Screenshot showing simple table idea

Screenshot showing table idea as referenced in my last comment


Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

It can be done pretty easy, but the solution depends on the details. Export to separate spreads is a more or less universal task (it wouldn't hurt if you tell what a profile you're using. 'High Quality Print'? ), but the naming can be done differently. I can be taken from the data-file (csv?) or from the layout (but it's need to see how the layout is made, probably it's need to assign some name the text frames). So, could you provide a sample of your date file and a couple of spreads (IDML)? No need any private info, just an empty layout.

I just added a simply solution. Probably it will be enough if you can copy/paste the list of model numbers in a text frame.

Hi Yuri!! You helped me last year with an automation that was super helpful. I hope you've been well!

Thank you so much for responding. I'm seeing what you say about the export process, so now it's just a matter of figuring out how to get each PDF named with the model number from the spread.
I'm going to edit my post to add some screenshots. The first one shows the spread layout with the data merge tags showing, and any private info hidden. It is the field called Product Code that I need as the name of each PDF.
Cont'd in next comment...

I don't have a table with the Product Code in it, but I was thinking that I could make a hidden layer with a simple 1 column 2 row table with text in the top row and the Product Code in the second row, as shown in the second screenshot. Would that make it easy for a script to find that cell and use it to name the exported PDF?
The data merge will still import the info even when the layer is hidden and locked. I don't know if a script could search a hidden/locked layer though. Perhaps I could simply make this tiny table very small and simply hide it behind the gray or blue backgrounds.CONTD

The idea is to make something the script could easily parse to grab the Product Code.

Hi, Sean! Yes, script can find tables on hidden layers and use info from them. So, let assume for every spread the name of the PDF is the text from first cell of second row of first table on the hidden layer with name 'Hidden Layer Test'. Sounds fine. I'll show how it can be done soon.

I just added the new variant of the script. Btw I think probably it would be even easier don't add the hidden layer but just to apply a character or paragraph style upon the product code text instead. Then the script could find all the texts with that style and to obtain the names this way. Let me know if it makes sense for your workflow.

Hi Yuri! I tested the script and it works perfectly! Thank you so much!
The High Quality Print is actually the setting we'll be using, but I am curious as to how I would change that if we ever decided to go with a different preset.
I see this line below, but I'm not sure what I'd change.
var pdf_preset = app.pdfExportPresets[0]; // High Quality Print

You can change the number [0] to something else [1] or [2] etc. Or you can use the method itemByName(). Something like this: var pdf_preset = app.pdfExportPresets.itemByName("Name of the preset is here").

Understood. Thanks again, man! I really appreciate your help!

Here is the variant of the script which takes the names of the PDF files from first cell of second row of first table on the hidden layer with name 'Hidden Text Test':
var doc = app.activeDocument;
var pdf_preset = app.pdfExportPresets[0]; // High Quality Print
var folder = doc.filePath // save into the same folder as the active document
var hidden_layer_name = 'Hidden Text Test';

var table, layer_name, pdf_file_name, page_num;

var tables = doc.stories.everyItem().tables.everyItem().getElements();

for (var i=0; i<tables.length; i++) {
    table = tables[i];
    layer_name = table.parent.itemLayer.name;
    if (layer_name != hidden_layer_name) continue;

    page_num = parseInt(table.parent.parentPage.name);
    pdf_file_name = table.rows[1].cells[0].contents;
    export_spread(page_num, folder, pdf_file_name);
}

function export_spread(page, folder, name) {
    var pdf_file = File(folder + '/' + name + '.pdf');
    app.pdfExportPreferences.pageRange = page + '-' + (page+1);
    doc.exportFile(ExportFormat.pdfType, pdf_file, false, pdf_preset);
}


A simplest solution is here:
if (app.selection.length == 0) {
    alert('Select a text frame with a list of names');
    exit();
}

var frame = app.selection[0];

if (!(frame instanceof TextFrame || frame instanceof InsertionPoint)) {
    alert('Select a text frame with a list of names');
    exit();
}

if (frame instanceof InsertionPoint) frame = frame.parent.textContainers[0];

var doc = app.activeDocument;
var names = frame.contents.split('\r');
var pdf_preset = app.pdfExportPresets[0]; // High Quality Print

var start_page = 2; // start from a second page
var pdf_folder = doc.filePath // save to the same folder as the active document

for (var i=0; i<names.length; i++) {
    var pdf_file = File(pdf_folder + '/' + names[i] + '.pdf');
    var page = start_page + i*2;
    app.pdfExportPreferences.pageRange = page + '-' + (page+1);
    doc.exportFile(ExportFormat.pdfType, pdf_file, false, pdf_preset);
}

Script takes the list of names from selected frame (you can copy/paste manually it from your csv/xlsx date file) and exports the spreads into PDFs with names from the list.

The result:


If you need to change a PDF-export profile or something else, let me know.

I'm adding a third screenshot that maybe better visualizes the table idea. Each spread will have this two cell table on it, with the model number, and the script would find that cell and use the model number from that table to name the PDF made of that spread. So for example, with the screenshot I added, the resulting three PDFs would be named MC12.pdf , MC34.pdf , MC34-MT.pdf
